# 1989 Dodge 250 V8 318 camper van

Tags: electrical, dodge, engine-swap

I have a 1989 Dodge 250 V8 318 camper van that I took the motor out of and put it in a swamp buggy the computer has a diagram on it that says it requires an 8 volt supply to one of the wires but I have a 12 volt system how would I supply 8 volts to this ECU using my 12 volt battery system and if anybody has any knowledge about that model of engine and TBI injection I'm trying to get an inquiry of how to supply power to the right wires of the system like a wiring diagram or colored wire diagram at least please and thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you post an image of the wiring diagram you're talking about? Please edit your original post to do so.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.